# Handler call to notifyDataSetChanged() not executing

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, handler, adapter

I have an Handler registered in an Activity.  handleMessage() calls notifyDataSetChanged on an  Adapter.  Things work while the Activity has initial focus.  However, when I navigate out of the Activity and back in, notifyDataSetChanged() does not work.

FileAdapter is an ArrayAdapter.  MergeAdapter is a custom class by CommonsWare.  _mergeAdapter contains _fileAdapter.

Activity code:

```
 public void setUpDownloadHandler() {
// Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress
_downloadHandler = new Handler() {
   public void handleMessage(Message message) {
       super.handleMessage(message);
       String fileId = (String) message.obj;
       int progress = message.arg1;
       FileInfo tempFile = null;
       for (FileInfo file: _files) {
   if (file.getFileId().equals(fileId)) {
                    file.setDownloadProgress(progress);
                    tempFile = file;
                }
            }
           if (tempFile != null) {
               _files.remove(tempFile);
               _files.add(tempFile);
           }
           _fileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           _mergeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   };
}
```

Passing the handler:

```
RunnableTask task = new DownloadFileRunnableImpl(application, the_workspace_url, the_file_info, the_workspace_info.getTitle(), the_internal_storage_directory,
                _downloadHandler);
```

Background thread code:

```
if(temp > previous) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.arg1 = _currentProgress.intValue();
    message.obj = _fileId;
    _progressHandler.sendMessage(message);
    previous = temp;
}
```

The other piece of information is that I'm passing the handler through a Binder and then into the runnable.  I do this to run the background thread in a Service.  I don't think this is the problem.

**EDIT:**
It seems like the handler is not associated with the activity the second time it is navigated to (perhaps because onCreate creates a new handler).  Is there a way to re-associate or retain the old handler?

**Update**
The activity is being destroyed when it loses focus to another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try putting a log message in your activity's onDestroy method to see if it is getting destroyed, when you navigate away from your activity. So your task may have the handler from the old activity.

Comment: Ok.  If the handler is destroyed won't it lose its connection with the background thread and not update the new activity?

Comment: that's what I think is happening. It may be something else also though, that's why I think you should check for the log message. Or you can run it in debug mode and put a break in the activity's onDestroy and see if it is being called.

Comment: I checked and the Activity isn't being destroyed when I navigate away from it.  When I navigate back in, it creates a new handler in onCreate().

Comment: your new activity isn't connected to the old handler. So your new activity will not get messages from the old task. Will continue to think about how to solve this, but am hoping someone will chime in. Could possibly look into broadcast receivers, but your new activity may be created then have to wait some time before the broadcaster sends out a message.

Comment: I was previously using broadcast receivers and they are too slow for this purpose.  I read that handlers are attached to threads.  I'm wondering if there is a way to recover the old handler and use it in the new activity..

Comment: What about using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to retain the handler between activity changes?

Comment: I think that onRetainNonConfiguration method has been depracated. I'm trying to make it work with FragmentRetainInstance.java example at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html   but am having some difficulties. I'm sure it must work but my case is a little different. Will post if I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, I relied heavily on  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html

Really just took their code and changed it so that I have to remake the fragment everytime I want to start the thread (work) again. And it communicates with the Activity through a handler.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements WorkProgressListener {

private static final String TAG = "tag";

private Handler handler;

private Button startWorkBtn;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private boolean onSaveInstanceFlag = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG,"Main onCreate " + Utils.getThreadId());

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler = new ProgressHandler();

    startWorkBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.start_work_btn);
    startWorkBtn.setEnabled(false);
    startWorkBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        Log.i("tag","Main: startWorkBtn onClick ");
        startWorkBtn.setEnabled(false);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment workF = (Fragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("work");
        if (null == workF) {
            workF = new WorkFragment();
            Log.i(TAG,"Main new WorkF" + Utils.getThreadId());

            startProgressDialog(true);
            startWorkBtn.setEnabled(false);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(workF, "work").commit();
            Log.i(TAG,"Main add(workF) " + Utils.getThreadId());

        }   
        else {
            // should never be able to get here.
        }               
    }           
});

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    Fragment loadingFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("work");
    Log.i(TAG,"Main findFragment " + Utils.getThreadId());

    if (null == loadingFragment) {
        this.startWorkBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }  
    else {
        // could also decide to show progress dialog based on savedInstanceState
        this.startProgressDialog(true);
    }

} // end onCreate

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    Log.i(TAG,"Main onRestart " + Utils.getThreadId() );
    super.onRestart();
    this.onSaveInstanceFlag = false;
}


@Override
public void onResume () {
    Log.i(TAG,"Main onResume " + Utils.getThreadId());
    super.onResume();
    this.onSaveInstanceFlag = false;
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Main onSaveInstanceState "+ Utils.getThreadId());

    this.onSaveInstanceFlag = true;

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (null != this.progressDialog) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("progressDialog", true);
    }
    else {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("progressDialog", false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop () {
    Log.i(TAG,"Main onStop " + Utils.getThreadId());
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy () {
    Log.i(TAG,"Main onDestroy " + Utils.getThreadId());     
    super.onDestroy();
    this.closeProgressDialog();
    this.handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}   


public class ProgressHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Main ProgressDialogHandler handleMessage");
        Bundle b = msg.getData();           
        boolean isDone = b.getBoolean("isDone");
        String tag = b.getString("tag");

        if (isDone && !onSaveInstanceFlag) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment loader = (Fragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);

            fm.beginTransaction().remove(loader).commit();

            closeProgressDialog();
            Main.this.startWorkBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }       
}


@Override
public void sendProgress(String tag, int progress, int max) {
    if ( progress == max) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Main sendProgress " + Utils.getThreadId());
        Message message = handler.obtainMessage();          
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("isDone", true);
        b.putString("tag",tag);
        message.setData(b);
        this.handler.sendMessage(message);
    }       

}

private void startProgressDialog(boolean show) {
    this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    this.progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
    this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.progressDialog.show();
}

private void closeProgressDialog() {
    if (null != this.progressDialog) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
        this.progressDialog = null;
    }       
}   

} // end Main
```

public class WorkFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String TAG = "tag";

private boolean mReady = false;
private boolean mQuiting = false;

private boolean done = false;

public WorkFragment () {}

final Thread mThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run () {

    synchronized(this) {
            while (!mReady) {
                Log.i(TAG,"WorkF notReady"+ Utils.getThreadId());               

                if (mQuiting) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        } // end synchronized


        Log.i(TAG,"WorkF starting work "+ Utils.getThreadId());             

        try {
            Log.i(TAG,"WorkF about to sleep"+ Utils.getThreadId());             

            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000l);

            Log.i(TAG,"WorkF almost finished "+ Utils.getThreadId());               

            done = true;

        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized(this) {
            while (!mReady) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Activity notReady"+ Utils.getThreadId());                

                if (mQuiting) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            ((WorkProgressListener)getActivity()).sendProgress(WorkFragment.this.getTag(), 100, 100);

        } // end synchronized 2
    }

};


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
     Log.i(TAG,"WorkF, onAttach: "+ Utils.getThreadId());   

}

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Log.i(TAG,"WorkF, onCreate: "+ Utils.getThreadId());   

     setRetainInstance(true);

     mThread.start();
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     Log.i(TAG,"WorkF, onActivityCreated: "+ Utils.getThreadId());  

     if (done) {
         ((WorkProgressListener)getActivity()).sendProgress(WorkFragment.this.getTag(), 100, 100);
     }

     synchronized (mThread) {
         mReady = true;
         mThread.notify();
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart()
 {
     super.onStart();
     Log.i(TAG,"WorkF, onStart: "+ Utils.getThreadId() );   

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     synchronized (mThread) {
         mReady = false;
         mQuiting = true;
         mThread.notify();
     }

     super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDetach() {
     synchronized (mThread) {
         mReady = false;
         mThread.notify();
     }

     super.onDetach();
 }

 public void restart() {
     synchronized (mThread) {
         mThread.notify();
     }
 }
}// end WorkFragment

public interface WorkProgressListener {

public void sendProgress (String tag, int progress, int max);

}
```

Comment: Changed the second synchronized work statement from a for loop to an if statement, so that if a new activity is made the thread isn't waiting till infinity.   if (null != WorkFragment.this){ if (mReady){ ((WorkProgressListener).getActivity()).sendProgress(....):}}

Comment: oops- rewrite "so if a new activity ISN'T made the thread isn't waiting till infinity"